# ¿Cómo le asigno valores a los elementos de un array dependiendo de su cercanía al mayor en java?

Tags: java, array

Tengo que entregar un programa para mañana y me tranqué en una parte, no se cómo asignarle un valor a los elementos de un array según su cercanía al número mayor.
No se si me expliqué bien, lo que quiero hacer es modificar el valor de las posiciones para que el mayor sea 100, el que le sigue 80, luego 60, 40, 20, y el más bajo 0
Por ahora solo pude encontrar el mayor, pero no sé como seguir

```
    int mayor=-1, puntos=100;
    int []vasos=new int [6];

    vasos [0]=rnd.nextInt(100);
    vasos [1]=rnd.nextInt(100);
    vasos [2]=rnd.nextInt(100);
    vasos [3]=rnd.nextInt(100);
    vasos [4]=rnd.nextInt(100);
    vasos [5]=rnd.nextInt(100);

    for (int i=0;i<vasos.length;i++){
        if (vasos[i]>mayor){
               mayor = vasos[i];
               vasos[i] = puntos;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen lo que se conoce como métodos de ordenamiento, como el método burbuja, quicksort, etc

```
       for(int i = 0; i < vasos.length - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < vasos.length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (vasos[j] < vasos[j + 1])
                {
                    int tmp = vasos[j+1];
                    vasos[j+1] = vasos[j];
                    vasos[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < vasos.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(vasos[i]+"\n");
        }
```

Este ejemplo es el del burbuja, analízalo ya que te será muy útil para la lógica

Más info: https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/Java/2666-Metodo-de-ordenacion-de-Burbuja.html